# Ag-grid custom tooltip position change

Tags: angular, tooltip, ag-grid, angular9, ag-grid-angular

How to change the position of the custom tooltip? Example: always show in the upper right corner of the table

Currently always show below the cursor:
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSmSo.png)

I want to display it in the upper right corner of the table: 
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoHpP.png)

Code example from the Ag-grid official website:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tooltip-component/#example-custom-tooltip

Thanks for the help!

Ag-grid version: 23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `tooltip-component` where the styles are automatically added by Ag-Grid.

Try adding the following CSS:

```
.ag-tooltip-custom {
  top: 5px !important;
  right: 14px !important;
  left: auto !important;
}
```

`!important` is important because we need to override the `style` given to the `tooltip-component`.

In the picture I have added to `.ag-popup-child` but you should add it to `.ag-tooltip-custom`. You can also play around with the numbers.[image]

[image]